# Return same row multiple times if search string matches with 2 columns - Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display the result from the following table

```
 id | string1 | string2

  1 | mysql   | php

  2 | mysql   | mysql

  3 | python  | java
```

Query I have tried

```
    SELECT id, string1
    FROM test 
    WHERE string1 LIKE '%mysql%' or string2 LIKE '%mysql%'
```

If I search the string 'mysql' in the table from column string1 and string2, I would like to get results as

```
1 mysql

 2 mysql

 2 mysql
```

Row id 2 should display multiple times as 'mysql' is presents in 2 columns(string1 and string2).

Is there any feasiblity to list like above results.

Note : I dont want to use UNION all

Thanks

Comment: Can you Please put your mysql query here

Comment: I'm affraid the only SQL solution will be to use `UNION ALL`. Would you acept a mixture of PHP and MySQL to achieve this?

Comment: @ Oscar Pérez : Already I have mixture of PHP and mysql. Now I have to optimize the process and make it within query.

Comment: What's wrong with UNION?

Comment: @strawberry UNION will only select the rows with same values once. So in this case you will get only 2 rows in result set: [1 mysql] and [2 mysql]

Comment: asim - I mean what's wrong with using a UNION type query.

Comment: @strawberry Ok fine. I think in this case UNION type query appears to be the only solution.

Comment: Please answer here what problem you are facing to use UNION ALL

Comment: My table is too large and I want to optimize the response time. It seems UNION ALL takes more time as there are 2 queries

Answer (score 0):

You can write two separate queries and then join them using UNION ALL keyword. Something like the following:

```
SELECT id, string1
FROM test 
WHERE string1 LIKE '%mysql%'

UNION ALL

SELECT id, string2
FROM test 
WHERE string2 LIKE '%mysql%';
```

Comment: @jai-lalawat If we do not use UNION ALL then what is the solution?